# Excel - Have a value from column B of a 2 column reference pasted anytime the value from column A is entered on a separate worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In the example I have a 2 column reference where data in column E is correlated to column F. I need the data in Column F to show up anytime data from Column E is entered in a separate worksheet if possible.

To be clear, is it possible to enter data in Column A of Sheet 1 that pulls the correlated data from column B in reference Sheet 2 and enters it into Column B of Sheet 1?

I tried using a simple function in a single sheet but it obviously doesn't do what I need.

[image: Data]

Comment: *In the example* Which example? What are your efforts? Where's your code?

Comment: Sorry I thought the example posted, it is now.  The formula references the reference cells but it just continues along as a list instead of searching for the specific value of the reference cell

Comment: @Jorricha: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [MCVE] , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and be sure to ask a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion),  include the code, expected  behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are after VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH

Sheet1 b1 and fill down rows

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!E:F,2,FALSE),TEXT(,))
```

Or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!F:F,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!E:E,0)),TEXT(,))
```

If you set you data up as tables the formulas will autofill down. Rather than use entire columns you can set to the ranges containing data.

---

Data:

[image: Data]